# How do I save all vim buffers on tmux window change?

Tags: vim, tmux

Is it possible to hook up vim save all command on tmux window change?

I know that gui vim has option to save on focus lost. I'd like to have similar behavior in console.

Answer (score 1):

Saving on lost focus is achieved through the following command in the .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * silent! wall
```

The syntax is:

```
:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}
```

In your case, you want to add `VimResized` to the list of events, see full doc [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimResized).

The final result in the .vimrc file looks like:

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,VimResized * silent! wall
```

Comment: I know about FocusLost. The thing is FocusLost is not triggered when I change tmux window. In my experience it works only for GUI vim, not for console one.